# jQuery Sortable table (or table style layout)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to render a table whereby the user can drag-and-drop the columns and rows into any order. I have used jQuery sortable to achieve this with div columns, or table rows, but what I want to achieve is the ability to drag both columns and rows.

For example:

```
(1)  (2)  (3) (4)
(a) row1 col1 col2
(b) row2 col2 col3
```

So in the diagram above the user would be able to swap the order of columns (2),(3) & (4), but also swap rows (a) & (b) Around as well. Column 1 would be fixed, as would the header row (1) and not made sortable.

I think I would probably have to achieve this with divs or something, but I think the logic would be quite complex.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this. I don't want the actual layout to look like a grid (excel style) or anything so don't want to use any of the existing excel style grid plugins. Each cell would be a nice rounded-corner div with a margin separating them all, so it would like like a series of bubbles all arranged in grid form, but completely sortable.

I hope you can help.

Comment: Well, just sorting table rows is easy – take the TR element and append/insert it at another place in the table. But for table cells it’s not that easy – because each of the cells that make up a “column” is in a different TR element. So you would have to do the same thing as when changing the position of a TR – but for each of the TDs affected individually.

Comment: Indeed, this is why the logic is complex and I am struggling to get my head around it. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

I used [johnny/jquery-sortable](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable).

I had to fix the col sorting code in the given example though ... [see it here](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable/issues/173).

Now table rows and cols are dnd.

Comment: Please describe here the main points of the solution, don't give only a link.